# How do I add an index column to a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am not sure if 'index' is the right word, as from searching on this site, it seems (to my limited knowledge) to be being used for other purposes, but what I would like to do is add a column at the start of a MySQL table which is a numeric index of the rows, i.e. the first row in the table would be numbered '1' the second '2' etc.  I would like this index to be automatically entered when a new row is added to my table with data via a form.

Could someone let me know how I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called PRIMARY key. You can add a INT value and add it as a primary key and give it AUTO_INCREMENT (so counting will automaticly increment every time you insert a new row).

SQL Statement:

```
  ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN `id` int(5) primary key not null auto_increment;
```

This will add a column 'id' to the table 'table' which increases with every new row.
Note that the number will not reset when deleting rows - so if you add a row it will have id=1, the next will have id=2, and even if you delete row 2, the next one inserted will have id=3.

Comment: Thanks.  When I run this I get the error "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to add "primary key".

Comment: I think you need to have primary key in the definition of any column that is auto_increment